# Linux - Want To Check For Possible Duplicate Directories (Probably RegEx Needed)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have a directory which contains several directories as follows:

/Music/
/Music/JoeBlogs-Back_In_Black-1980
/Music/JoeBlogs-Back_In_Black-(Remastered)-2003
/Music/JoeBlogs-Back_In_Black-(ReIssue)-1987
/Music/JoeBlogs-Thunder_Man-1947

I want a script to go through and tell me when there are 'possible' duplicates, in the example above it would pick up the following as possible duplicates from the directory list:

/Music/JoeBlogs-Back_In_Black-1980
/Music/JoeBlogs-Back_In_Black-(Remastered)-2003
/Music/JoeBlogs-Back_In_Black-(ReIssue)-1987

1) Is this possible?
2) If so please help!

Comment: You say you have several directories, but you have shown only 1 directory. What do the other directories look like? Is the second text field between dashes `JoeBlogs-Back_In_Black-1980` always the song name?

Answer (score 2):

Follow up:

I did what I need using by coding the the following Perl script. This is my first ever Perl script (and I had to learn Perl to write it - so don't be to hard on me :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# README
# 
# Checks a folder for Albums that are similar 
# eg : 
# Arist-Back_In_Black-(Remastered)-2001-XXX
# Artist-Back_In_Black-(Reissue)-2000-YYY
#
# Script prompts you for which one to "zz" (putting zz in front of the file name you can delete it later)
#
# CONFIG
# 
# Put your mp3 directory path in the $mp3dirpath variable
#

$mp3dirpath = '/data/downloads/MP3';

# END CONFIG


@txt= qx{ls $mp3dirpath};


sort (@txt);

$re1='.*?'; 
$re2='(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)';
$re3='.*?';
$re4='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))';

$re=$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4;

$foreach_count_before=0; #Setups up counter
$foreach_count_after=1; #Setups up counter


$number_in_arry = scalar (@txt);

while ($foreach_count_before < $number_in_arry) {
                                        if ($txt[$foreach_count_before] =~ m/$re/is)
                                            { 
                                             $var1=$1;
                                             }
                                         if ($txt[$foreach_count_after] =~ m/$re/is)
                                            { 
                                             $var2=$1;
                                             }
                                         if ($var1 eq $var2)
                                            {
                                             print "-------------------------------------\n";
                                             print "$txt[$foreach_count_before] \n";
                                             print "MATCHES \n";
                                             print "\n$txt[$foreach_count_after] \n";
                                             print "Which Should I Remove? \n";
                                             print "[1] $txt[$foreach_count_before]\n";
                                             print "[2] $txt[$foreach_count_after]\n";
                                             print "[Any Other Key] Take No Action\n\n";

                                             $answer = <>;        # Get user input, assign it to the variable 
                                                if    ( $answer == "1" ) { 
                                                      print "ZZing $txt[$foreach_count_before]";
                                                      $originalfilename = $mp3dirpath . '/' . $txt[$foreach_count_before];
                                                      $newfilename = $mp3dirpath . '/' . 'zz' . $txt[$foreach_count_before];
                                                      $originalfilename = trim($originalfilename);
                                                      $newfilename = trim($newfilename);
                                                      qx(mv $originalfilename $newfilename);
                                                } 
                                                elsif ( $answer == "2" ) { 
                                                      print "ZZing $txt[$foreach_count_after]";
                                                      $originalfilename = $mp3dirpath . '/' . $txt[$foreach_count_after];
                                                      $newfilename = $mp3dirpath . '/' . 'zz' . $txt[$foreach_count_after];
                                                      $originalfilename = trim($originalfilename);
                                                      $newfilename = trim($newfilename);
                                                      print "mv $originalfilename $newfilename";
                                                      qx(mv $originalfilename $newfilename);
                                                } 
                                                else { 
                                                      print "Taking No Action"; 
                                                }

                                            }

                                           $foreach_count_before++;
                                           $foreach_count_after++;

                                        }

# SubRoutine For Trimming White Space from variables
sub trim($)
{
 my $string = shift;
 $string =~ s/^\s+//;
 $string =~ s/\s+$//;
 return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your directory names follow a regular structure such as:

```
foo-Name_of_Interest-bar
```

then you can do a simple regex to strip off the "foo-" and the "-bar" and do a direct comparison.

If that's not possible, you'll have to do a much more expensive pattern match algorithm. Perhaps something like [longest common sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) or [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). There may be other techniques that are more appropriate.

Simple matching in Bash (version 3.2 or higher) might look like this snippet:

```
dir='/Music/JoeBlogs-Back_In_Black-(Remastered)-2003'
regex='^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-(.*)$'
if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == ${prev_dir[1]} &&    #  "/Music/JoeBlogs"
      ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} == ${prev_dir[2]} ]]    #  "Back_In_Black"
then
    echo "we have a match"
fi
```

This snippet doesn't show a `find ... | while read ...` loop or how previous entries and lists of matches could be handled.